# Getting values like 9.071E+11 and 7.12121E+11

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

i have a column that is supposed to give me a big number but instead i am getting exponential values

i change the display size but im getting the same result

ALTER TABLE inventario MODIFY COLUMN no_serie VARCHAR(100);

Comment: You're storing a number in a varchar column? Then look into whatever's formatting the number as a string when it's being inserted into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value a a numeric:

```
ALTER TABLE inventario MODIFY COLUMN no_serie NUMERIC(38, 0);  -- or whatever is appropriate
```

Comment: the problem is that in the column no_serie i have values like PM1618105593